# Why I obtain this error when I try to create a JavaScript Date object (using Rhino into a Java application)?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

I developed a JavaScript script that process a JSON document and creates a new JSON document using the information contained in the original one.

In the browser my script works fine. The problem is that this script have no to run in the browser but is performed into a Java application using **Rhino** that is a tool that allows to run JavaScript tasks into a Java application (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Rhino).

The problem is that, running it into Rhino I am obtaining a strange behavior (and an error) with the Date.

I try to explain you the problem in details.

In my code I have something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < payload.forecast.length; ++i) { 
    log.info("ITERATION: " + i);

    currentOriginalForecast = payload.forecast[i];          
    console.log("currentOriginalForecast CONTENT:  " + JSON.stringify(currentOriginalForecast));
    console.log("CURRENT DATE: " + currentOriginalForecast.start_date);

    var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date(currentOriginalForecast.start_date);     
    console.log("dateCurrentOriginalForecast: " + dateCurrentOriginalForecast);

    .....................................................................................
    .....................................................................................
    .....................................................................................
}
```

As you can see I am iterating on the object contained into a JSON array named **forecast** (it works fine).

This line:

```
console.log("currentOriginalForecast CONTENT:  " + JSON.stringify(currentOriginalForecast));
```

correctly print the content of the current object, that is something like this:

```
{
    "start_date": "2017-11-09 06:00:00",
    "main": {
        "min_temp": 15,
        "max_temp": 24
    },
    "weather": {
        "meteo_forecast_id": 17,
        "meteo_forecast_description_id": 1,
        "meteo_forecast_description_name": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "meteo_forecast_description": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "meteo_forecast_description_audio_link": "audio_link.html",
        "icon_link": "Light_Rain.png"
    },
    "advice": {
        "meteo_advice_id": 3,
        "meteo_advice_description": "METEO-ADVICE-3",
        "crop_id": 3,
        "crop_name": "millet",
        "planting_date": "2017-10-17+02:00",
        "harvesting_date": {
            "@nil": "true"
        },
        "meteo_advice_audiolink": "AUDIO-LINK-3.HTML"
    }
}
```

Also this log line:

```
console.log("CURRENT DATE: " + currentOriginalForecast.start_date);
```

returns the expected value, infact I obtain in the shell:

```
CURRENT DATE: 2017-11-09 06:00:00
```

And now my problem occurs when I try to do:

```
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date(currentOriginalForecast.start_date);
```

Here it seems that **Rhino** goes into error (using the standard JavaScript interpreter into the browser it works fine) and in the shell I obtain the following error message:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-09 11:10:08,915]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext} -  dateCurrentOriginalForecast: Invalid Date {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-09 11:10:08,918] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: RangeError: Date is invalid. (<Unknown Source>#137) in <Unknown Source> at line number 137
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:345)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:233)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: RangeError: Date is invalid. (<Unknown Source>#137)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate.toISOString(NativeDate.java:398)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate.execIdCall(NativeDate.java:384)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__538._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:137)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__538.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__538.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__538.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        ... 16 more
```

So it seems that **Rhino** interpreter doesn't allows this kind of date (**2017-11-09 06:00:00**) passed as parameter of the **Date()** constructor.

Why? What could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue? Maybe is something related to a different version of JavaScript?

Comment: What locale does rhino use?

Comment: How is the date generated? Could you change this to be ISO format? 2017-11-09T06:00:00.000Z

Comment: @Razzildinho I am not so into JS. What have I to do?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, you are to use correct string format to represent a date. Rhino uses ISO format for dates, like the one in above comment. Your format is not supported.

Comment: More specifically, constructor for `Date` in rhino that receives CharSequence expects date to be in [ISO-8601](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html) format or an extended format with ISO time appended after `T` character.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Ok, and can I convert it in some way? Can you please show me how (I am not into JS)

Comment: Well, where is the date coming from? Javascript doesn't really support date parsing or formatting. ECMAScript does define some rules, but they aren't fully compliant with ISO 8601, so native parsing (unless it is in Rhino only, which you seem to say it's not) is no good. You can include third-party JS library built for parsing. I liked Moment.js when I had to deal with these things.

Comment: Where does the string "2017-11-09 06:00:00" come from? If that is replaced with "2017-11-09T06:00:00.000Z" then it should work. [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Unfortunately I can't use third party library or frameworks because this is a Rhino version embedded into WSO2 ESB (an ESB tool based on Java)

Comment: In this case, you *have* to make sure the dates in your data is sanitized before they are passed to your script.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov So can I use JavaScript to convert the string "2017-11-09 06:00:00" into a string compliant with  ISO-8601 before use it to create the Date object? How?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, if you specifically want to use JavaScript, and don't want to or cannot add a Js library that specialized in that, you will have to write a date parser yourself. JavaScript only has one date parser, and it's `new Date` which doesn't work for you.

Comment: Rhino does have a `require()` mechanism, by the way (at least in a form of pluggable extension).